# document.getElementById(...) is null after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net

**Background:** I have an asp.net page that contains videos as learning resources.  When a user finishes watching a video it gets marked as 'watched' and an entry is made in an SQL database.

**Approach:**  I have some JS that detects when the video has finished and then fires a JS function that fires a hidden asp:button's click event which in turn fires a vb.net codebehind function that makes some visual changes to show the video for that section has been watched.

**Problem:** When the video has finished, the JS function fires but cannot then find the asp:button by id

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

**Code:**

```
<asp:button runat="server" ID="videoEndedButton" Text="SubmitVideo" style="display:none;" onclick="videoEndedButton_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('pdp_video_rta').addEventListener('ended', videoEnded, false);
    function videoEnded(e) {
         document.getElementById("videoEndedButton").click
    }
</script>
```

Why can't the JS function find the asp:button (long after the page has loaded).  I can click the button and run the code-behind function just fine (when it is not hidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= videoEndedButton.ClientID %>').click();
```

because 
asp **server** side id
 need to convert **client** side id.

Comment: Ah, this is what I needed and has fixed my issue.  I was trying to target the asp server side element like an HTML client side element.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your asp:Button you need to add property  ClientIDMode="Static" .

Comment: This made no difference in my case.

Comment: you also need "()" in document.getElementById("videoEndedButton").click(). Also may be you need to specify ClientIDMode="Static" for your videoEndedButton element.